# Facebook How to Format HTML Page so that Share picks up an image

Tags: image, facebook, share

When I use facebook.com/share.php?u=mysite.com, what must I do in my index.html document so that it gets an image as well?

Setting Title and META Description will populate the title and the description of the link.

I don't know how to do that to show an image. (index.html has Flash in it, no images).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://example.com/img.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, I must admit I'm a bit confused right now.

There used to be a page here

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share/Specifying_Meta_Tags

That covered all this, but now it just redirects to here

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

So I'm not sure if they're trying to get rid of "Facebook Share" and wholesale replace it with the Like Button or what - there's nothing in the [developer blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/), [live status](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status), or [roadmap](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Developer_Roadmap) about it.

I suppose you can try specifying an `<og:image>` attribute and then testing it the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and see what happens.

### EDIT

I opened a [forum topic](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=257153) about this.

### EDIT 2

Documentation now located here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share